# CSS bootstrap conflict duplicate select option

Tags: html, css

Hello this is my first post
I am new to web development and having a wired issue .
when i add select options  it gets a dublicate text just below it which is labelled as no 2 and i dont want it .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdgpX.png)
my html code

```
                            <select>
                        <option value="Hafizabad">Pakistan</option>
                        <option value="Hafizabad">USA</option>
                        <option value="Hafizabad">Russia</option>
                            </select>
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular the part about providing a [mcve]

Comment: Add the code, not an image. The code help us to know what you are doing and after seeing what you have done to fix it, and can help.

Answer (score -2):

Please check that options are given inside the select element like below

```
<select>
  <option value="one">One</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yes they are                  <select>
                         <option value="Hafizabad">Pakistan</option>
                         <option value="Hafizabad">USA</option>
                         <option value="Hafizabad">Russia</option>
                             </select>

Comment: Please share me the html file

Comment: how can I share html file i am new to this site so I don't know how to share files

Comment: Please paste the whole content in the description